# Noise pollution: Highway vs river

Tags: rivers

Recently, I noticed that a highway and a river sound fairly similar. This got me thinking that they say noise pollution from highways causes stress even if you don't really notice it. So, the question is: "Can the noise from a river also be considered as noise pollution (for humans) and cause similar levels of stress."

Disclaimer: I am not really familiar with environmental sciences

Comment: have you ever camped close to a river or by the sea? because if you have you will know the answer to your question.

Comment: Only once, but the noise was already less where I slept, so it didn't really bother me.

Comment: There's no horns or sudden squeals of tires in the river sound (though nature can bring other surprises like trees falling and animals rustling).  So it's an interesting question :-)  I did get quite used to the sounds of the highway in the distance in places I've lived... or even planes flying overhead when I lived near a runway.  Probably similar for people and animals near rivers (though wouldn't be surprised if there's an unrealized background physiological stress added in all cases)